# Is it possible to deactivate Spring Integration check for existing message channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have two modules(A,B) that are dependent on another module(C). 
Module A configures a MessageChannel as a Bean and the module C has the MessagingGateway with the configurated requestChannel of module A. Module B **does not** refer this MessagingGateway and therefore not configures a requestChannel.

In normal Server startup all modules are loaded and it will work fine, because module A provides the MessageChannel Bean for the gateway.

If I test Module B the application context cannot be loaded, because of the missing MessageChannel Bean, that the MessagingGateway in module c has as configured message channel.

Before updating to Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE (Spring Integration 5.1) my test-class did not failure cause of a missing MessageChannel Bean and the Application Context loaded although no MessagingChannel was given.

Is it possible to condition that a Gateway does not loads the configured messageChannel for test purpose like i described above?

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {

   @Gateway(requestChannel = "myMessageChannel")
   Future<Response> request(Response response);

}
```

Greetings Timo

EDIT Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'CHANNEL_REQUEST_TURNS_FOR_CONVERSATION' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CHANNEL_REQUEST_TURNS_FOR_CONVERSATION' available
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:117) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:367) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer$NodeFactory.gatewayNode(IntegrationGraphServer.java:355) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer$NodeFactory.access$400(IntegrationGraphServer.java:341) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.lambda$gateways$5(IntegrationGraphServer.java:248) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet.lambda$entryConsumer$0(Collections.java:1575) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1696) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1600) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.gateways(IntegrationGraphServer.java:253) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.buildGraph(IntegrationGraphServer.java:174) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:62) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CHANNEL_REQUEST_TURNS_FOR_CONVERSATION' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a test `@Configuration` where you would declare that channel as a bean just for test purpose.

On the other hand it isn't clear how it can fail for you since the `requestChannel` is lazy-loaded in the gateway. In other words it isn't going to be resolved as a bean from name until you call some gateway operation. From here it is confusing a bit how your test is going to work if you would like to ignore that gateway.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the stack trace!

Now it is fully clear what is going on. Starting with Spring Boot 2.1 there is a new actuator endpoint `/integrationgraph`. This one brings for us an `IntegrationGraphServer` bean which tried to build the whole graph of integration components and connections between them.

This endpoint is enabled by default. I don't think that you need it for this particular test. just exclude and try again:

```
management.endpoint.integrationgraph.enabled=false
```

Comment: Our current solution is that we defined the bean within the scope of the gateway. But since we want to separate the modules, it would be best if the channel bean is defined in module A and the gateway is defined in module B. At runtime, both modules are loaded and the gateway can find the channel. That should work if the gateway loads the channel definition lazy, but since the upgrade to Boot 2.1 it stopped working. It now seems that the gateway loads the channel eager. Does an @IntegrationComponentScan trigger the gateway to evaluate the channel name?

Comment: With the upgrade we just changed the import statements of the MessageChannels class. Everything else stayed the same.

Comment: Sounds strange... Would you mind to share a stack trace to determine at what point the gateway fails? Our idea is to have it as lazy as possible, not sure what have changed there, but we are fully open for fixes!

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Worked fine, thank you very much! 
Next time i will provide the stacktrace at first ^^